# Font in editor for editing posts has become proportional

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, design, editor

When [edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/306954/edit)ing a post, the font in the edit box with source code for the post is proportional:

[image]

This does not happen when [posting new questions](/questions/ask) or answers:

[image]

Tested with the latest Firefox and Safari on macOS High Sierra.

Comment: also confirmed on Chrome/Win10.

Comment: Confirmed on Edge.

Comment: Confirmed, Chrome 64/Win7x64SP1, also Firefox 57 and 58 (both 64bit) same workstation.

Comment: Confirmed on Safari 11.0.1 (Sierra)

Comment: Confirmed on Firefox ESR on Linux.

Comment: Also on meta.stackoverflow.com ~ https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363337/weird-proportional-font-while-editing-a-question-or-answer

Comment: @AdamLear As of this instant, this seems to have been fixed.

Comment: @Ano As a general rule, give the people working on it a chance to post an answer. I don't need an immediate ping. ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Fixed now, sorry it took so long. We're currently working on making our CSS more maintainable, but during work like that, ten years<sup>1</sup> of technical front-end debt sometimes come back to bite you in the rear.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Yes, Stack Overflow is coming up on its tenth anniversary  this year!</sub>

Comment: I hope you have enough rear left then to be bitten in ...

Comment: As of right now, NOT COMPLETELY FIXED in ELU; comment editor is using Georgia.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin AFAIK the comment editor always has been using a proportional font.

Comment: @Glorfindel - yes, but the font that it used always seemed to be the same font that the comments appear in - which is a sans-serif font for ELU, but the comment editor right now is using Georgia, the serif font used for questions and answers, but not comments.

Comment: Thanks for making StackOverflow usable again.