# Extra margin when editing About Me

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

Edit your profile here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current

[image]

Tested on Windows 10 v1709:

- Google Chrome 64.0.3282.119 (Official Build) (64-bit): [Download](https://www.google.com/chrome/)
- Mozilla Firefox 57 and 58
- Internet Explorer 11 (Updated KB4074736)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed in the next build, thanks for noticing. Fallout from [this fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306983/115866).

Comment: By *fallout*, do you mean this bug was introduced while fixing that one?